# defer loading elements until Flash gallery’s images from XML file finish loading

Tags: javascript, flash, image, loading

How would you defer loading of other graphics on the page until after the images in a Flash gallery’s images.xml file are finished loading?

Is there any way to detect for this, or would I only be able to check if the flash swf object is finished loading?

I'm pretty sure the swf object would be loaded/ready as with `document.getElementById('flashobject').onload = function(){};` before the corresponding images have loaded though, instead of after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call a javascript function from inside your swf file once you know it's time to load the other images on the page.

Something in the lines of:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
ExternalInterface.call("loadImages()"); // loadImages is a javascript function defined inside your webpage
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Do you think there are any non-actionscript ways to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to accomplish it without using actionscript. You can wait for the swf to be loaded but that doesn't guaranty you that the images will be loaded correctly at that point. A complicated solution would involve asking the server to tell you (with an ajax callback function for example) when a specific image was loaded from a particular session ID. But I think that this approach may create new problems and cost you too much time. Why is editing the actionscript not an option?

Comment: It's an option, so I'll try it after I see if I can reduce the size of the images (since the real problem is that they all take so long to load). I'm just less familiar with Flash and actionscript.